# How can I make the hover background same height as the menu?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the hover background same height as the menu? I can't get this right yet.

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="">About us</a></li>
            <li> <a href="">Benefits</a></li>        
            <li> <a href="">How it Works</a></li>
            <li> <a href="sex">Contact us</a></li>
            <li> <a href="">Get Started</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Css Starting here

```
#menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: list-item;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 60px;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 60x;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Am I missing a position tag here?

Answer (score 0):

You Have given Hover For `ancho`r tag.Then it will affect only in the anchor tag.If you want fully you just hive hover to the `li` tag

```
  <style type="text/css">
 #menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: list-item;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 60px;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:1%;
    height: 60px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 60x;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: darkcyan;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `"line-height"` in `a:` hover.

You set the `height: auto;`

Please chang it and give some height.
For example, if you give **10px height**, then you set `"line-height: 10px;"`

If you have done this then you see a same height..

Answer (score 0):

You can make this:

```
#menu ul li a{
   display: block;
}
```